# Point to coordinate function

Tags: algorithm, angles, trigonometry

I am working on a game in which I need an enemy ship to point towards the player.

Here is the equation I came up with:

> angle = sin<sup>-1</sup>(<sup>abs(y<sub>1</sub> - y<sub>2</sub>)</sup>/<sub>√(x<sub>1</sub> - x<sub>2</sub>)<sup>2</sup>-(y<sub>1</sub> - y<sub>2</sub>)<sup>2</sup></sub>)

This essentially takes the inverse sine of the opposite divided by the hypotenuse. Unfortunately, this algorithm does not work. **Any ideas as to what I need to change?** *Note, the angle is a radian value.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

atan2(y1-y2, x1-x2)
or maybe atan2(-(y1-y2), x1-x2), depending on the coordinate system.